# Why does np.arccos(1.0) give nan if fed by np.arange?

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry

Can anyone replicate this?

```
import numpy as np
print np.arccos(1.0)
print np.arccos(1)
for x in np.arange(0.7,1,0.05):
    print x
    print np.arccos(x)
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.0
0.7
0.795398830184
0.75
0.722734247813
0.8
0.643501108793
0.85
0.55481103298
0.9
0.451026811796
0.95
0.317560429292
1.0
nan
```

Note the last value,which should be `np.arccos(1.0)`, is `nan`. When I do `np.arccos(1.0)` in the console it is `0.0` as I would expect. What is causing this behaviour?

Note, I am using Python 2.7.6 Spyder IDE Win7

Comment: Yes - I can replicate this behaviour on 2.7.6, but I don't know why!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is normal floating point inaccuracy. Adding 0.05 many times to 0.7 does not necessarily add up to 1 exactly.

Changing `print x` to `print repr(x)` outputs 1.0000000000000002 for the last `x`.

```
>>> np.arccos(1.0000000000000002)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos
nan
```